How to explain why I don't have a reference letter from my supervisor
I have an upcoming interview for an academic position and I anticipate being questioned about the absence of my PhD supervisor as a reference. I would like to address this proactively and professionally.
The story: I completed my PhD two years ago and transitioned to a postdoctoral position at a different institute. When requested to write a reference letter a while ago, my PhD supervisor suggested co-authorship on two of my current research papers—despite having made no substantive contributions to these works. I respectfully declined this request, as it would have been inappropriate to add an author who did not contribute to the research.
Question: How should I approach discussing this situation with the selection committee? Would it be better to provide a direct, unfiltered account of what occurred, or should I carefully navigate the conversation to avoid direct criticism of my former supervisor? I lean towards the latter approach, as a straightforward critique might come across as overly accusatory, particularly in the Canadian academic context of the university I'm applying to.
Additional note: I have enough reference letters from my MSc and my postdoc supervisors and a co-supervisor.

Also consider that you might never be asked such a question, I also never requested recommendations from my PhD supervisor, and nobody has ever asked about it.

Rather than your MSc supervisor, is there anyone else beyond your PhD supervisor who could attest to your PhD work ? That's the classic way to sidestep the issue.

Rule No. 1: don't say anything bad about past employers unless it's already publicly known.

I feel your story with the supervisor ends prematurely. You declined. How did they react? Was there some fallout? Did you even ask him about a reference letter?

@quarague I would judge the PhD supervisor's behavior unethical. I would not ask for a reference. No fallout necessary.

Your PhD was two years ago and you have a more recent reference from your postdoc advisor. Nothing needs to be said about not choosing your PhD advisor as a referee. If I were on the selection committee, I wouldn’t even wonder about it unless your PhD advisor was so famous that even dropping their name would open doors — and that seems unlikely if they are scrounging for unearned co-authorships.
If anyone does say anything, it should be your postdoc advisor in their reference letter, not you.

Myth vs. Reality. The myth: a recommendation letter is used to gauge the merit of the candidate. The reality: a recommendation letter is used in a post hoc fashion. If the hiring official is enthusiastic about the applicant – they'll find positives in the letter to support their positive decision. If same the hiring official is unenthusiastic about the applicant – they'll search for something, anything, including a missing letter from a PHD advisor, to support their negative decision. Bottom line: don't give a recommendation letter more weight than it truly has. And yes, that's in biomedical fields. Perhaps especially in biomedical fields. Good luck.

Reality: over my years serving on numerous search committees, there has been a significant shift towards stricter HR oversight, and prolonged discussion of every candidate, which has now included their letters. Unfortunately, yes it does not look good when you lack a letter from your doctoral advisor, especially if you are in your first postdoc, just a few years out. This signals that there was a problem because your doctoral advisor should be your biggest advocate. The further you get away from your doctoral time, and build more professional contacts, the weight decreases.

@R1NaNo HR is like the plague: no brains, best avoided :D

Different panels operate differently. I've been on panels that contacted referees before finalising the short-list to interview, so the referee comments were a big part of our first impressions. I've been on panels that contacted referees to help decide between two leading candidates after interviews. And I've been on panels that operate as you say, contacting referees only after the real decision has already been made.

@AH May ask what is your background and experience in academic hiring committees? Your answer paints a picture that is very much unlike my experience (tenured professor at R1 where my main service has been interdisciplinary hiring committees across the college of science and engineering).

@Karl Yes HR has certainly made things more difficult, but I think the overall outcomes for the applicants are more fair. Also, I can appreciate that departmental and college HR liaisons present at our meetings have resulted in very consistent meeting schedules and we have stayed on task way better than before. It has also held faculty accountable that previously did not pull their weight on such committees. So yes, some issues aside, especially in dealing with people who are not subject matter or field experts can be aggravating, the overall outcome is positive (in my opinion).

In my 30+ years of experience (math, R1 university), the reality is a mixture. Most faculty involved in the hiring process are simply unable to judge candidate's quality. (Typically, because their area of research is too far from candidate's work.) Accordingly, they look for other ways to evaluate the candidate: Which college/grad school/postdoc  did they go to, where did they publish, who wrote their recommendation letters and what did they say in the letters, and the order of these items varies greatly.

Well you made it to the interview so presumably it’s not that important for the hiring committee.  Moreover if the committee is really worried they can contact your PhD supervisor.
If asked you can just state that experiences with more recent supervisors are better representatives of your best output at and enthusiasm for research.
